# Ionic 2 Failed to push to another page from Forms in Modal

Tags: ionic2

```
<form [formGroup]="variation" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <ion-list radio-group formControlName="color" *ngFor="let option of options">
  <ion-list-header>
    {{option.name}}
  </ion-list-header>

  <ion-item *ngFor="let opt of option.options">
    <ion-label>{{opt}}</ion-label>
    <ion-radio value="{{opt}}"></ion-radio>
    <!--<ion-input type="text" formControlName="color" name="color" value=""></ion-input>-->
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
<button class="custom-button" block (click)="goToCart()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Above is my forms in modal
I failed to push to another page from Forms in Modal.
Below is my push to another page method

```
goToCart() {
    this.nav.setRoot(CartPage);
}
```

Below picture is after I clicked submit button in the form, the modal only slided half

[Image to display problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ih2To.png)

This is the code:

https://github.com/vinnchan/FormInModal

This app include first page that allow to click and open modal. You click the open modal button.
After that you click submit button and go to cart page. 
Now you at cart page, when you click the side menu, it won't open.
I viewed the browser console pane, showed no error(s).

Answer (score 0):

Try to dismiss the modal when submitting:

```
<button class="custom-button" block (click)="goToCart();dismiss();">Submit</button>
```